# Android Layout not working well on other devices

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I recently developed an Android app and uploaded it to the PlayStore. When users were testing it, the view was all messed up because of the size of the screen of the different devices (unfortunately, I had been able to test it on only one phone). This is how it should look:

[image]

Instead, the buttons and controls overlap eachother and its not very nice.
I did some research and found this [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). It talks about the different layout folders you can make and the density of the resources used.

Unfortunately, I don't have all the mobile devices with different screens to test the app and go fixing the layout and an Android Virtual Device is not posible since my app uses the Google Maps API and it can't be run on emulators.

**Questions**
Is there any other way for me to fix the layout?
Do I need to resize or do any change to the images that I use when I put them in the drawable-hdpi/ldpi/mdpi/etcdpi or simply drop the same image on the different folders?

Here goes my layout.xml file in case it helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonModifymarker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Modificar marcador" 
        android:background="@drawable/bluebutton" 
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/markerTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonModifymarker"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Título"
        android:background="@drawable/editwhite"
         >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/markerDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/markerTitle"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Descripción"
        android:background="@drawable/editwhite" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAccept"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonModifymarker"
        android:text="Insertar" 
        android:background="@drawable/yellowbutton"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonModifymarker"
        android:text="Cancelar"
        android:background="@drawable/redbutton"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonAccept"
        android:text="Guardar"
        android:background="@drawable/greenbutton"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDeletemarker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bluebutton"
        android:text="Borrar"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerColor"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/markerTitle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/markerTitle" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/whitebutton"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonRight"
        android:background="@drawable/leftarrow" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonChangemap"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonChangemap"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/lupa" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonChangemap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonLeft"
        android:background="@drawable/changemap3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonSearch"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:background="@drawable/editwhite"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOK"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editplaceholder"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editplaceholder"
        android:text="GO" 
        android:background="@drawable/gobutton"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editplaceholder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonSearch"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:ems="10" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonHelp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editplaceholder"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonSearch"
        android:src="@drawable/help" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonplaceholder"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rightarrow" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/buttonplaceholder"
         style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editplaceholder"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editplaceholder"
         android:text="GO" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonLang"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editplaceholder"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonHelp"
        android:src="@drawable/language" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonTrazaruta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/purplebutton"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Trazar ruta" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonUpdateMarker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonTrazaruta"
        android:background="@drawable/yellowbutton"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Modificar marcador"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPositionToMarker"
        android:layout_width="71dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/markerTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/markerTitle"
        android:background="@drawable/greybutton"
        android:text="Trazar ruta desde posición actual al marcador elegido"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMarkerToMarker"
        android:layout_width="71dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/markerTitle"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonLang"
        android:background="@drawable/greybutton"
        android:text="Trazar ruta desde este marcador a otro"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="83dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonTrazaruta"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/whitebutton" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioAndando"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Voy andando"
          />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioVehiculo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:text="Voy en vehículo"
             />

    </RadioGroup>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerMarkers"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonLang"
        android:background="@drawable/whitebutton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerColor" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can create a layout for every screen density and resolution. Create a folder for layout-???dpi (same as for drawables)

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to read Supporting Multiple Screens documentation in Android Developers. There is a lot of techniques you can use. You can also try android emulator at different resolutions and sizes. Just fiddle a bit with AVD.

Check more info about supporting multiple screens @ http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

To create and test AVDs with different resolutions, just check the same documentation @ http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing and create an AVD for that effect.

Comment: When using the AVD the layout seems alright, but when testing on a real device its still messed up. I mentioned that I checked that page in my post. Just one question, Do I need to resize or do any change to the images that I use when I put them in the drawable-hdpi/ldpi/mdpi/etcdpi or I just simply drop the same image on the different folders?

Comment: Also, it always loads the layout.xml from the "default" folder, never from the folder layout-large/small/Etc

Comment: Each folder (HDPI,LDPI,MDPI) corresponds to different resolutions and sizes of images. If MDPI has an asset of 10x10, then xHDPI would need an image of 20x20. But that is not the case because android automatically resizes and downsizes (even if it loses quality) the assets. Create an AVD with the resolution of the phone that is clearly having issues. Besides from that use RelativeLayout. It is weird that AVD displays correctly and device does not. My guess is you didn't test in AVD with same settings as the device.